# What is the correct term for the "major axis" of an oblong?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Suppose you have an oblong, with a line extending across its length. The line begins and ends at the midpoints of the shorter sides. What is the correct term for this line? Major axis seems to be reserved for ellipses. Would long axis be correct?

Similarly, what is the correct term for the shorter side? Length certainly seems to denote the distance along the greater dimension, but does width explicitly mean the distance along the shorter side?

Comment: diagonal is the keyword, not axis

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "oblong"? That's not usually used as a formal geometric object, and can have several geometric meanings depending on who you ask.

Comment: By oblong, I just mean a rectangle that isn't a square.

@Arjang: wouldn't diagonal be the line that goes from corner to corner? That's not what I'm describing here.

Comment: @spaceiver , yes you are correct, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the definition you use for oblong, the answer ends up being "these lines don't have widely accepted names".

**Since you've defined an oblong as a non-square rectangle:** In this case, I'm not aware of any particular name for the lines you describe. That's because there's nothing particularly fundamental about them as far as the geometry of the rectangle goes.

For an ellipse, the major and minor axes are an important part of understanding its geometry, and it's useful to have the shorthand of a name to refer to them with since they'll often be talked about. For a rectangle these lines are just lines that are parallel to two of the rectangle's sides and pass through the midpoints of the other sides - they're not particularly special in terms of understanding the rectangle. They are equal in length to the long and short sides (for which the terms "long side" and "short side" work fine), so if it's just their length you want, use side lengths to talk about it.

I'll add that **the term "oblong" itself is something of a gray area:** this is not a universally used term for a non-square rectangle, and moreover has several other widely used meanings (including two circles joined by a rectangle, a rectangle with rounded corners, and any roughly rectangular or ellipsoidal shape). If your goal is good communication, remember that finding the exact right name for something is sometimes less desirable than a concise, unambiguous description.

Comment: thanks very much, that's a great answer. I should have done more homework before using the term oblong. I mistakenly thought it was equivalent in meaning to a non square rectangle.

Comment: Happy to help. I ended up editing the answer to focus more on the definition you were using before I saw your comment, but the gist of it is the same. :)

Comment: @spacediver Also, welcome to Math.SE! If you believe this answered your question, consider accepting it. Or, to use the rather stiff boilerplate comment template: "After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/)."

Comment: ah, good call! done.